# Problems with caching query plans within a single postgres db session

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a long-running postgres db session where I repeatedly execute a PL/pgSQL function containing a pretty complex (but static) sql query (which uses the function variables). For this complex sql query, I routinely see (via explain-analyze) that the planning time far exceeds the execution time. Hence I would like to see if I can get a performance boost by forcing postgres to use a cached *generic* query plan on repeated invocations. However, I'm having difficulty achieving this. Here is what I did to force postgres to use a cached generic query plan

- set `plan_cache_mode = force_generic_plan` in `postgresql.conf` file

To examine if a generic query plan is being used every time, I also set the following logging parameters in `postgresql.conf`

- set `log_planner_stats = on`
- turn on auto-explain by setting

  - `shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'`
  - `auto_explain.log_min_duration = '0s'`
  - `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = 'ON'` (I had to specify this otherwise auto-explain was not printing the explain output of the complex sql query within the PL/pgSQL function, it was just printing the explain output of the function call itself, which was not very useful)

After restarting the server, when the PL/pgSQL function was executed repeatedly (more than 10 times), I don't see caching happening in any of the invocations. When I examined the logs, I do see a `LOG:  PLANNER STATISTICS` line specified for the complex query for every time the function was executed, which I assume means that planning also happened every time (i.e. no caching). But the query plan logged by the auto-explain module contains `$n` variables, which makes me think that generic plan was indeed used every time, but it was just not cached.

I would like the know the following:

- Did I miss anything in the steps I took to force postgres to use the cached generic plan on repeated invocations?
- Can the query plan be cached for any arbitrarily complex sql query in a PL/pgSQL function, as long as it is static or is there a limitation on what kind of queries can be cached? (My complex sql query references views and uses recursive ctes for instance)
- Is there a way to view the contents of the query plan cache? From what I understand, `shared_buffers` is used to cache query plans. It looks like `pg_buffercache` module can be used to view its contents. However it is not clear to me how to see if a specific query plan has been cached and if a cache hit occurs when you execute the same query again?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  With force_generic_plan, I get two PLANNER STATISTICS blocks for the first time I call (one for planning the `select my_func(7)`, one for planning the inner query) and just one PLANNER STATISTICS block forever after in that session.  With auto, I get two blocks for the first 6 runs, and one forever after for that session.  For force_custom_plan, I get two blocks each time, forever.

Comment: Can you share the function definition?  Or at least the decorations, like signature, return type, variable declarations, IMMUTABLE, etc.?